# Redondear centésimas hacia arriba (C++)

Tags: c++

Cómo hago para redondear un número, solo unas centésimas siempre hacia arriba, por ejemplo redondear 0,554444 para que quede 0,56 en C++

Comment: Veo que eres nuevo en el sitio, podrías colocar lo que has intentado.?

Comment: Sin, embargo sería bastante simple lo que necesitas, multiplica el número por 100 aplicas un ceil y lo divides entre 100.

Answer (score 2):

Con el metodo ceil de la librería math.h puedes redondear un número flotante hacia arriba, para llegar a redondear la centena podrías multiplicar tu número por 100.
`0.55444 * 100 = 55.444`

Por lo que si le aplicas el `ceil(55.444)` obtendrás `56.0` al dividirlo nuevamente entre 100 obtendrás el número que buscas `56.0 / 100 = 0.56`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
  double myNumber = 0.554444, result ;
  result= ceil(myNumber*100)/100;
  printf ( "Result is %.2f\n", result );
  return 0;
}
```

Espero sea útil.

Comment: Ya queda más explicado, Gracias @BetaM